# Network Monitoring in Sharepoint?

Tags: 2013, office-365, diagnostics, monitoring, network

Is there a network monitoring tool that displays in sharepoint? I'd like to be able to see some server status/network traffic kind of info.  I'm interested in something free but am willing to spend the money if there is something that meets the needs perfectly.

-thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not at server side if your interested in Office 365 server status. Your only options are client side tools, but they don't measure server performance.